# The most efficient and fastest way to categorise data in dataframes and save in R

Tags: r, loops

I have 1000 dataframes importing from 1000 different txt files as below.

```
Surname Name   Type Age Dept
Gold    Craige  1   24  100
Goodwin Madison 1   41  49
Young   Emma    2   31  34
Young   Rose    2   26  3
Young   Brad    2   42  76
Young   Kim     2   30  100
Smith   Emma    2   18  50
Smith   Kim     2   21  70
Hacksaw Ben     2   33  88
Hacksaw Richard 2   28  77
Hacksaw Charles 2   49  250
```

Based on the Type column, each df needs to be categorised and saved as below: 
 if Type =1, save the related row into an individual xlsx file naming as Surename.

if Type=2, create a folder naming as the surname in Column A and save individual xlsx files for each name based on column B.

What I currently do is using the split function for each Type and put a loop for type 1 and a nested loop for Type 2 to create surname folders and individual name xlsx files as below which is very time-consuming (more than 13 hours to finish). The semi code is as below.

```
for (i in 1:lenght(file_names))

rawdata <- read the data frame [i]


TYPE1 <- rawdata %>% filter(TYPE == "1") 
TYPE2 <- rawdata %>% filter(TYPE == "2") 

Split.TYPE1 <- split(TYPE1, TYPE1$Surname) 
Split.TYPE2 <- split(TYPE2, TYPE2$Surname) 


#--------------------------------- Save the TYPE 1 reports---------------------------------------
for (nm in names(Split.TYPE1)){
  file<-paste0(nm,".xlsx")
  d1<-as.data.frame(Split.TYPE1[[nm]])

  wb<-createWorkbook(file)
  addWorksheet(wb, "test", gridLines = T)
  writeData(wb, sheet = "test", x = d1)
  saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
}

# #------------------------------ Save the TYPE 2 in a folder ----------------------------------
for (dn in names(Split.TYPE2)){
   dnn <- paste0(dn)
  dir.create(dnn)
  sub_Split.TYPE2 <- split(Split.TYPE2[[dn]], Split.TYPE2[[dn]]$Name)
  for (fn in names(sub_Split.TYPE2)){
    file<-file.path(dnn, paste0(fn,".xlsx"))

    d1<-as.data.frame(sub_Split.TYPE2[[fn]])

wb<-createWorkbook(file)
    addWorksheet(wb, "test", gridLines = T)
    writeData(wb, sheet = "test", x = d1)
    saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
  }}
gc()
}
```

I am just wondering if there is a faster and more optimised method to generate the same outputs using fewer loops. Applying parallel(foreach package) computing did not speed up that much.

Thanks.

Comment: you can rbind all of the data together (idcol from data.table's method may help) then do these operations `by` group all at once.

Comment: The data size is 12 gigabytes. Not possible

Comment: It is worth investigating which part of the script is taking the longest time, for example using the system.time() function. You can gain some speed by replacing the for loops with lapply, but I suspect most of the time is taken by constructing the Excel files and writing them out. What package are you using for Excel?

Comment: Hi. I have done some test. Most time consuming part is the second nested loop. And I’m using openxlsx as i use formatting.

Comment: You can use the pattern in my answer below to convert the nested for loops into lapply function calls. This should give you some speedup. I have used both openxlsx and xlsx packages, and openxlsx is much much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to convert the last nested loop into calls to lapply.

```
system.time({
    for (dn in names(Split.TYPE2)){
        dnn <- paste0(dn)
        ## do something with dnn
        sub_Split.TYPE2 <- split(Split.TYPE2[[dn]], Split.TYPE2[[dn]]$Name)
        for (fn in names(sub_Split.TYPE2)){
            d1<-as.data.frame(sub_Split.TYPE2[[fn]])
            ## do something with d1
        }
    }
})

system.time({
    lapply(Split.TYPE2, function(spl) {
        dnn = spl$Surname[1]
        ## do something with dnn
        sub_Split.TYPE2 = split(spl, spl$Name)
        lapply(sub_Split.TYPE2, function(d1) {
            ## do something with d1
        })
    })
})
```

Alternative approach, using a single lapply for the nested loop. Also shows conversion of the first loop:

```
## setting drop=TRUE ensures that each split has at least 1 row, which allows
## you to extract the split value, e.g. Surname
Split.TYPE1 <- split(TYPE1, TYPE1$Surname, drop=TRUE) 
Split.TYPE2a <- split(TYPE2, TYPE2[,c("Surname", "Name")], drop=TRUE)


##--------------------------------- Save the TYPE 1 reports---------------------------------------
lapply(Split.TYPE1, function(d1) {
    nm = d1$Surname[1]
    ## use nm and d1 as before
}

##------------------------------ Save the TYPE 2 in a folder ----------------------------------
lapply(Split.TYPE2a, function(d1) {
    dnn = d1$Surname[1]
    fn = d1$Name[1]
    ## you may want to move dnn out of lapply, otherwise the same directory name
    ## will be used multiple times
    ##
    ## use fn and d1 as before
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you believe that lapply makes it faster? Can it be applied on the other for loop as well then for reading or saving the individual files?

Comment: Yes, you will definitely see a speedup. How much will depend on the number of iterations through the loop. The more iterations, the better the speedup. Another factor is the amount of time spent on the Excel processing. If this is slow, then you will not gain that much by eliminating the for loop. Here is where some detailed, line by line benchmarking is helpful. You should definitely convert the for the loop over TYPE1 data as well. You can leave the for loop that reads the data. Looping over 1000 file names is OK.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go and update you here. Any idea hoe can I convert the first for loop to lapply as well using that saveworkboom function, please?  Also do you thing apply foreach on top of this new method helps?

Comment: I have edited my answer, showing how to convert the first loop, and also how you can avoid nesting lapply.

Comment: Thanks for putting these things together. In the first approach, in the nested loop I could not find out how to use fn. In the second approach, I did not get your comment in the code as " the same directory name will be used multiple time". Can you please clarify. I couldn't apply the second approach on my file yet.

Comment: I couldn't apply the second approach on my file yet because there is an error in this line: "   d1<-as.data.frame(sub_Split.raw2[[fn]])". How should this line be changed to match with the second approach please.

Comment: And a quick update, the first approach on a case 500,000 observations reduced the computation time from 210 secs using the nested for loops to 180 secs using nested Lapply loops. So saved 30 secs! Still interested to know how the second approach with no nested loop works :) . I can't define  " d1<-as.data.frame(sub_Split.raw2[[fn]])" in the second approach though to save the dataframes.

Comment: Nice to see actual benchmarks. In the lappy version without nesting, the split is done by both variables at the same time. d1 is already available as the argument of the anonymous function, no need for the assignment. Follow directly with wb<-createWorkbook(file).

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly, I will update about computation time. Just two quick questions: 1- Time-wise, is there any difference between Lapply and Sapply? 2- Can Lapply be applied on my first for loop where it reads the dfs one by one as well aiming to speed up the process? Foreach package did not help that much.

Comment: 1. I haven't compared run times of sapply and lapply. sapply does additional steps, trying to be smart about coercing certain results into vectors, but my guess is that it would not slow things down significantly. 2. It is possible, of course, to convert any for loop into lapply. Reading 1000 file in a for loop is ok. I would not expect to see much difference if you used lapply instead.